# Table View Multiple Segues

Tags: uitableview, pushviewcontroller

Hi There im creating an app using table views in storyboards and so far i am able to populate the table i have it set to making 4 cells and push to the same view controller from each cell but what i want to be able to do is each cell takes me to a new view controller

Here is what i have so far if you could point me in the right direction in to how to be able to do this would be great

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSimpleDetails"]) {
    SimpleTutorialsViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    int row = [myIndexPath row];
    detailViewController.simpleDetailModal = @[_simpleTitle[row], _simpleDescription[row], _simpleImages[row]];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in the storyboard or in code:

**In Storyboard**

You can draw a segue from a cell to a destination view controller and give that segue a unique identifier in the property inspector. You can use this to segue to multiple destinations by having multiple cell prototypes, with each prototype having its own segue.

**In Code**

To do it in code, you would draw a segue from your view controller (not the cell) to each destination and give each segue a unique identifier. Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you would decide which destination you want based on the selected index path and perform the segue like

```
NSString *segueIdentifier = @"someIdentifier";//or whatever logic you need to determined the appropriate identifier
id sender = self;//or whatever object you want to be the sender
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:sender];
```

**prepareForSegue**

In `prepareForSegue`, you'd have a conditional block for each possible segue identifier:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"oneSegueIdentifier"]) {
        //preparation
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"anotherSegueIdentifier"]) {
        //other preparation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to click on the TableViewController > TableView > Attributes Inspector> Prototype Cells = numberOfSeguqes you want to make.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a ctrl+drag from prototype cell to different destination view controllers and assign different identifiers.

Say you have a prototype cell and four different destination view controllers. Follow below steps

1. ctrl+ drag from prototype cell to First destination view controller and assign a identifier in attributes inspector say "cell2view1"
2. ctrl+ drag from prototype cell to Second destination view controller and assign a identifier in attributes inspector say "cell2view2"
3. ctrl+ drag from prototype cell to Third destination view controller and assign a identifier in attributes inspector say "cell2view3"
4. ctrl+ drag from prototype cell to Fourth destination view controller and assign a identifier in attributes inspector say "cell2view4"

Your [segue destinationViewcontroller] will be automatically set according to your storyboard.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"cell2view1"]) 
    {
        //Do things
    }
    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"cell2view2"])
    {

    }
 }
```